# Java make batch file for multiple package structure?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to create my client side application window, I am using multiple packages.
src/nu/connect/client/* contains all the logic and chat window itself.
src/nu/connect/message/* contains the MessageStructure class file.

```
javac -d bin src\nu\connect\client\*.java
javac -d bin -cp bin src\nu\connect\client\ChatWindow.java
java -cp bin nu.connect.client.ChatWindow 
pause
```

Here is the error I am getting,when i run the batch file:

```
src\nu\connect\client\ChatWindow.java:7: error: package com.message does not exist.
```

Comment: Compile all the files at once. ChatWindow depends on the package com.message, which has not been compiled yet. You should also learn how to use a real build tool like gradle, instead of using javac directly.

Comment: This a requirement in my assignment, I have to do it the batch way.How do i compile all files at once?

Comment: Okay I got what I was looking for after you gave me the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem, had to compile both packages in one line.

```
javac -d bin src\nu\connect\client\*.java src\nu\connect\message\*.java
javac -d bin -cp bin nu\connect\client\ChatWindow.java
java -cp bin nu.connect.client.ChatWindow

pause
```